# Tela de Consentimento do Google não abre

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure, oauth2

Fiz uma aplicação que tem a função de fazer backup para o Google Drive, porém ela não funciona quando coloco em algum servidor, funciona apenas em `localhost`.

O que acontece é que ela não abre a tela de consentimento nos servidores, segue o código:

```
var credencial = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets 
    { 
        ClientId = clienteID, 
        ClientSecret = clienteSenha 
    }, 
    scopes,
    NomeUsuario,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("C:\\temp\\items/" + empresaAtiva, true)).Result;

var servico = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credencial,
    ApplicationName = "items",
});
```

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573272/googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync-hangs

Answer (score 1):

É muito provável que o problema seja esse acesso à arquivo usando `FileDataStore`. Certamente, no Azure, vc não terá acesso à esse caminho. Especialmente se tiver usando Azure App Service.

Existem várias maneiras de contornar isso, mas é certo que não poderá acessar o disco dessa maneira "negligente".

Próximo é, veja as configurações do seu aplicativo dentro do painel de desenvolvedor do Google. Pois lá vc deve configurar qual domínio poderá tentar se conectar usando o token do seu app. É provável que agora tenha apenas `localhost`, então vc deve adicionar o domínio da sua app no Azure como um dos possíveis a se conectarem.

Comment: Então Thiago no caso do azure eu tenho uma Virtual Machine, mesmo nesse caso o FileDataStore não funcionaria?

Comment: No caso de VM, desde que a aplicacao esteja rodando com credencias para acessarem o disco, deve funcionar.